# Error no member named 'reqevents'; did you mean 'events' when building Redis on AIX

Tags: c, redis, aix

I'm upgrading from Redis 6.0.13 to 6.2.5 on AIX.

On 6.2.5, the build fails with this error:

```
MAKE hdr_histogram
cd hdr_histogram && make
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/jenkins/redis/deps/hdr_histogram'
/opt/atc-2.0/opt/gcc/bin/gcc  -Wall -Os -g -DLUA_USE_POSIX -DLUA_USE_DLOPEN -include stdint-gcc.h -c  hdr_histogram.c
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/jenkins/redis/deps/hdr_histogram'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jenkins/redis/deps'
    CC adlist.o
    CC quicklist.o
    CC ae.o
In file included from ae.c:60:
ae_select.c: In function 'aeApiResize':
ae_select.c:52:37: warning: unused parameter 'eventLoop' [-Wunused-parameter]
   52 | static int aeApiResize(aeEventLoop *eventLoop, int setsize) {
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/poll.h:30,
                 from ae.c:41:
ae_select.c: In function 'aeApiPoll':
ae_select.c:89:43: error: 'aeEventLoop' has no member named 'reqevents'; did you mean 'events'?
   89 |             aeFileEvent *fe = &eventLoop->events[j];
      |                                           ^~~~~~
ae.c: In function 'aeCreateEventLoop':
ae.c:73:16: error: 'aeEventLoop' has no member named 'reqevents'; did you mean 'events'?
   73 |     eventLoop->events = zmalloc(sizeof(aeFileEvent)*setsize);
      |                ^~~~~~

...
```

I checked the eventLoop struct, and it does indeed contain `events`, but I see the build failing because it's trying to access `reqevents`. I can't find `reqevents` anywhere in the project (with `grep -R 'reqevents' .`)

This error only happens on AIX 7.1 - Linux and macOS both work fine.

Do you know why `req` would be prepended to the struct members on AIX, and how I might solve the error?

Comment: Most likely a stray `#define` from some header.

Comment: `usr/include/sys/poll.h` does this; different workarounds are possible, e.g. migrating to 64-bit (gcc-option `-maix64`)

Comment: Turns out I can solve this by setting `export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -include poll.h"`

I'm already on a 64 bit gcc, and build with `-maix64`.

Thanks for the input @LorinczyZsigmond!